# MYSQL alter table current_time default error

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

I tried to alter the table with inserting a new attribute date1 where it will auto set the date for each entry into the table.

When i insert the query

```
ALTER TABLE `vessellist` ADD `date1` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FIRST;
```

It says INVALID DEFAULT VALUE FOR date1

Comment: The data types CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can be used as a default field value for is limited, and varies by version of MySQL. In earlier versions, I believe only TIMESTAMP fields could use it; in more recent onces, I think DATETIME can also; but I am not sure if DATE can.

Comment: Thanks. Now i understand. I've changed the datatype and there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html